# ASP.NET 4.5 Forms Authentication after hosting

Tags: asp.net

I have a .NET 4.5 Forms application that works great locally. Does not require any authentication and I can use all pages. However, I am able to register user, log in and log out without any problems.
On godaddy, I can get to an HTML page I put on godaddy so everything is setup fine. But when I try to go to Default.aspx, I get a log in error even though nothing is requiring authentication locally. When I try to register a user, I get this error below.

One thing I noticed is that my application is 4.5 and this error shows 4.0 at the bottom. Now on godaddy, they just say you are using 4.0/4.5. There is no separation between them. I have talked to godaddy few times but they say they have very little technical help for custom sites like this and I have to resolve these. But if the .NET version is the problem, I will convert my projects or recreate them in 4.0.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5296071    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308555
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +145
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +920
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions) +434
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +558
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +67
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +83    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +79
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +384
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +241
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +26
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +170
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.GetStorageMetadata(String
>   providerName, DbConnection connection, String ssdl) +35
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMetadataWorkspace(String
>   providerName, DbConnection connection, String csdl, String ssdl,
>   String msl) +154
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateEntityConnection(ConnectionStringSettings
>   setting, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +109
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings
>   setting) +28
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.Membership_CreateUser(String
>   applicationName, String userName, String password, String salt, String
>   email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean
>   isApproved, DateTime& createDate, Boolean uniqueEmail, Int32
>   passwordFormat, Object& providerUserKey) +51
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String
>   username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion,
>   String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey,
>   MembershipCreateStatus& status) +823
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser() +304
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs
>   e) +110    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +401
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +119
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>   +37    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +159
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a .NET 4.5 Forms application that works great locally. Does not
>   require any authentication and I can use all pages

If you run the application locally, Visual Studio uses SQL Express for development. As the result, it is working without even you notice it. Normally, the database is created inside `App_Data` folder.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

However, when you deploy the application (to GoDaddy), you need to explicitly provide the connection in web.config to connect to actual SQL Server.

According to the above error message, you did not provide the correct connection string in web.config.

Comment: Bulls eye. Thanks Win. My Trusted_Connection property in my connection string was wrong.